# table state not compatible with columns reordering when using the table component?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using version 12.2.3 of PrimeNg and the `p-table` component.
I need to resize columns and to reorder them, this is running perfectly.
But I also need to be able to save table state and as soon as I enable it, I can still drag columns but when I drop them nothing happens.

Is there a way to have all this running ?

Here is my table code:

```
  <p-table
    #dt
    selectionMode="multiple"
    scrollHeight="flex"
    responsiveLayout="stack"
    dataKey="id"
    [value]="data"
    [styleClass]="getTableClass()"
    [scrollable]="true"
    [rows]="20"
    [rowHover]="true"
    [resizableColumns]="true"
    [paginator]="true"
    [metaKeySelection]="true"
    [loading]="false"
    [globalFilterFields]="getGenericColumnsNames()"
    [filterDelay]="0"
    [(selection)]="selectedItems"
    [reorderableColumns]="true"
    [columns]="columns"
    columnResizeMode="expand"
    stateKey="notifications"
    stateStorage="local"
  >
```

And for the headers:

```
  <th
    [pSortableColumn]="column.id"
    [ngClass]="column?.size"
    class="header-title-table p-jc-between"
    pResizableColumn
    *ngIf="column.sortable"
    pReorderableColumn
  >
```

When I drop a column, I have this error message in the console:

```
zone.js:182 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'field')
    at primeng-table.js:1658:41
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Table.saveColumnOrder (primeng-table.js:1657:26)
    at Table.saveState (primeng-table.js:1548:18)
    at primeng-table.js:1440:34
    at timer (zone.js:2561:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:487:1)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:476:1)
```

Comment: Can you send a stackblitz example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from our implementation of the component, everything it running perfectly when creating a separate project with all the requirements.